# Handle different types of values in a List

Tags: java, object, data-structures, linked-list

I have a singly LinkedList called RankList. In that list I insert information such as ID,Map Point and Score of different shops.

**My code for that implementation:**

```
class RankList {
private Node first;
private int nodeCount;
private Record record;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Inserting values for a node
    //Data for the first node
    RankList list = new RankList();
    Point point = new Point(5.4, 3.2);
    Record record = new Record(1, point, 8.2);
    System.out.println(list.insert(record));
    double maxDist=point.dist(point);
    //Data for the second node
    Point point1 = new Point(1.4, 9.2);
    Record record1 = new Record(2, point1, 7.5);
    if((point1.dist(point)>maxDist)) maxDist=point1.dist(point);
    System.out.println(list.insert(record1));
    //Data for the third node
    Point point2 = new Point(2.2, 1.2);
    Record record2 = new Record(3, point2, 6.0);
    if((point2.dist(point1)>maxDist)) maxDist=point2.dist(point1);
    System.out.println(list.insert(record2));
    list.printList(); //Prints the list
}
```

The list that I get:

```
HEAD -> Rank[Identity Number: 1, Location at point: 5.4,3.2, Score: 8.2] -> Rank[Identity Number: 3, Location at point: 2.2,1.2, Score: 6.0] -> Rank[Identity Number: 2, Location at point: 1.4,9.2, Score: 7.5] -> null
```

Here comes the question. I need to implement a method called nearest with the following arguments.

```
public RankList nearest (Point p,double maxDist)
```

**NOTE:** Method nearest is in the class RankList scope.

In this method I need compare all the Points I have already inserted to the Ranklist with the Point p.

e.g `Point p = ( 2.2 , 4.4)` with all the `Locations at point`

It's hard to me to understand how to access only the Point object of a node in RankList in order to use it to the comparison.

I tried to implement this but it doesn't work at all because Point is out of scope.

```
public RankList nearest (Point p,double maxDist){
        RankList nearList = new RankList();

        Node current = first;
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.print(current);
            if(point.dist(p)<maxDist){ //Finding the distance between the added points with p argument 
                nearList.insert(record); //Insert the distances shorter than maxDist in a new list.
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println("null");
        return nearList;
        }
```

**Point class:**

```
class Point {
    public double x, y;
    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    //Distance between two points
    public double dist(Point p) {
        return Math.sqrt((this.x-p.x)*(this.x-p.x)+(this.y-p.y)*(this.y-p.y));
    }

   
    public Point copy() {
        return new Point(this.x, this.y);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "point: "+x+","+y;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you save the Point object inside a Record object, then surely you need to do `rankList.getRecord(2).getPoint()` ?

Or in your case, `current.getPoint()`

Comment: @JamieG I don't have anywhere getRecord or getPoint methods.

Comment: Can you paste the RankList & Record code